# com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I have MySQL under my Hibernate and I am also using c3p0-0.9.1 for connection pool.

When running on my laptop (I mean locally) I have no errors.
But when I deploy it on the server, I get this exception:

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
```

This is my stack trace:

```
    root cause

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
 org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:344)
 $Proxy8.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
 com.hposg.domain.HPOSG.getItstance(HPOSG.java:56)
 com.hposg.domain.Game.<init>(Game.java:43)
 com.hposg.domain.GlobalGame.<init>(GlobalGame.java:12)
 com.hposg.domain.SiteAdmin.createNewGame(SiteAdmin.java:18)
 com.hposg.controller.struts.InitializingAction.execute(InitializingAction.java:45)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
 org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
```

Answer (score 9):

Another problem which may cause this kind of exception is that your JDBC driver doesn't exists in the classpath ...

Comment: the actual adding is the issue. a guide would come in handy as everyone everywhere assumes it'll be self-evident but it's not.

Answer (score 7):

Some external problems and answers that might help:

- [Problem with c3p0](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=34157)
- [Problems to connect to mysql with hibernate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/216326/ORM/java/Problems-connect-mysql-hibernate)
- [java.sql.SQLException Connections Could not be Acquired from the Underlying Database!](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/java.sql.SQLException+Connections+Could+not+be+Acquired+from+the+Underlying+Database)

Please follow the links, they all cover problems with the same exception.

Comment: The third link (to atlassian confluence) was dead, but archive.org has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20090501161202/http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/java.sql.SQLException+Connections+Could+not+be+Acquired+from+the+Underlying+Database!

Comment: Wayback doesn't seem to have that archived anymore. :/

Comment: the moved the page here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/%27java.sql.SQLException+Connections+Could+not+be+Acquired+from+the+Underlying+Database%21%27+Error+During+Startup

Comment: It is here now: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/connections-could-not-be-acquired-from-the-underlying-database-104825087.html

Answer (score 1):

Your c3p0-config.xml or c3p0-config.properties is not getting loaded, make sure one of the file should be include in the classpath while deploying in server.

Answer (score 1):

Check your  database connection. When it is down can happen this exception

Answer (score 0):

Was missing a configuration property while setting up the ComboPooledDataSource ; was missing the jdbc driver name; when I set this - was able to get the connection;

Answer (score 0):

Check your JDBC driver version, I've got the same problem.
I'm using postgresql, I'd just updated the version in pom.xml and everything worked fine.