# Can't get c3p0 to work with Spring/Hibernate/JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I've configured my Spring application to work using Hibernate as the JPA provider.  Application context looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.med.persistence.magic.*"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Load DB config file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesMode">
            <util:constant
                static-field="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        </property>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:dev.db.properties</value>
<!--                <value>file:///usr/share/tomcat6/conf/hx_db.conf</value>-->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MagicPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxSize">25</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minSize">1</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">1</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">0</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">0</prop>-->
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT * FROM dual</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${JDBC.Driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${JDBC.ConnectionURL}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${JDBC.Username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${JDBC.Password}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run a simple unit test, it takes about 150 seconds to connect and validate the database tables.  However when I uncomment the c3p0 properties, I get the following exception after about 90 seconds.  I think I need to allow more time for the connection to be opened but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:507)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:269)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:162)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:374)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
        at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1245)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:55)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:332)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 42 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465872

Comment: I've already looked through most of those and they haven't really helped.  Much of it deals with stale connections and MySql, my issue here is getting a brand new connection (on application startup) from Oracle.  Also, this works fine with c3p0 turned off but once I enable it the application will no longer start.

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out.  I ended up turning on log4j and I saw a NullPointerException coming out of the JDBC drivers...this was never being thrown up the stack into the exception I was seeing before so there was no trace of the root cause anywhere.   I needed to specify the connection parameters inside the JPA properties like so:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MagicPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${JDBC.Driver}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${JDBC.ConnectionURL}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${JDBC.Username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${JDBC.Password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT * FROM dual</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have no idea why it's not picking the parameters up from the dataSource I gave to the EntityManager.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I guess this relates to the 3CP0 [Hibernate-specific notes](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific), which claims *"Hibernate's C3P0ConnectionProvider explicitly sets 7 c3p0 configuration properties, based on your hibernate configuration, overriding any configuration you may have set in a c3p0.properties file."*

Comment: (Which, by the way, uses slightly different property names.)