# spring hibernate mysql data base connectivity error.

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Actually, I have deployed my application in net4india web host and done each configuration. My website using mysql database its working fine with simple jsp(J2ee) code but when i switching into Hibernate+Mysql+spring then it giving exception. I have googled many times but didn't got proper solution please Help.

this is my spring-servlet.xml file Datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />

    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="500"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="1000"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="540"/>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000"/>
</bean>
```

Exception i am getting:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy2053.getAllMenus(Unknown Source)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.controllerHelper.UserControllerHelper.createNewSession(UserControllerHelper.java:56)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.UserController.index(UserController.java:185)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4088.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy2053.getAllMenus(Unknown Source)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.controllerHelper.UserControllerHelper.createNewSession(UserControllerHelper.java:56)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.UserController.index(UserController.java:185)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4088.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy2053.getAllMenus(Unknown Source)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.controllerHelper.UserControllerHelper.createNewSession(UserControllerHelper.java:56)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.UserController.index(UserController.java:185)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4088.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy2053.getAllMenus(Unknown Source)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.controllerHelper.UserControllerHelper.createNewSession(UserControllerHelper.java:56)
com.ecommerce.onlineshopping.User.controller.UserController.index(UserController.java:185)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4088.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
```

Comment: can you also share the hibernate properties? Maybe the problem is with your url or else

Comment: Here is the same question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465872/com-mchange-v2-resourcepool-cannotacquireresourceexception-a-resourcepool-could](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465872/com-mchange-v2-resourcepool-cannotacquireresourceexception-a-resourcepool-could)

Comment: Thank u  Burak Keceli for reply. Earlier i wrote properties file but now using hard coding .

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     
     <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/siwflowersmurthy" />
        <property name="user" value="siwflowersmurthy" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />

Comment: <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="21600"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="1000"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="5"/>

Comment: <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="10800"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000"/>
 </bean>

Comment: Burak Keceli plz tell where i need to correct. thanks