# Deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, war

How can I deploy a war file to Tomcat in exactly the same way Eclipse deploys to Tomcat, if I configured Tomcat in Eclipse?

Reason for asking is that when I deploy with Eclipse everything works fine (databse connection, log4j ect). But when I manually deploy the corresponding war file to the same Tomcat installation, none of my external resources like database connection, logging to files work!

Comment: Several question may arise.
1) Did you restart your tomcat after deploying?
2) Did you deploy your war file in same machine?
3) Is there any path set to your program that was static?
4) After updating in your code, did you press "Clean and Build button"?

Comment: it's difficult to give an answers without error messages... does your war file contain the libraries needed for logging, database connction and so on?

Comment: You can look here how to setup Tomcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579661/how-to-set-catalina-home-variable-in-windows-7

Comment: Yes, restarted, same machine. Not sure about 3. Tried with ant build as well, nothing works

Comment: All libs are there otherwise eclipse wouldnt make it

Comment: Please put your exception too. What exception thrown by your tomcat ? P.S: see it in tomcat console.

Comment: I started a thread about this problem before this. There are all outputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069832/tomcat-deployment-failing

Answer (score 0):

You can add the external jars to `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` Read [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

> Common — This class loader contains additional classes that are made
>   visible to both Tomcat internal classes and to all web applications

Comment: I will try it, but isnt it enough to have them in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Sorry, but what is your mean?

Comment: You tried to put the jar files /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application?

Comment: Yes and restarted tomcat

Comment: What is your log of server?

Comment: Log say that everything working, no warnings or errors.

Comment: So why do you know DB connecting that is not working?

Comment: Because items are not showing up on my page. See here, I started this thread before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069832/tomcat-deployment-failing