# Hibernate/Spring [BasicResourcePool Acquisition Attempt Failed!]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am getting the following error message while trying to build & run my application :

```
WARN  BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@66bcc265 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.embeddedDriverAcceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
WARN  BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1c0957f0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.embeddedDriverAcceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
```

HibernateConfig.java :

```
package de.fruuts.web.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException{
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(1800);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
        dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);       
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){     
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("db.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
        //hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("de.fruuts.db.entities").addProperties(hibernateProperties);                
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);       
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

jdbc.properties :

```
db.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
db.user=usr
db.password=pwd
```

pom.xml dependencies :

```
<properties>
        <hibernate.core.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.6</mysql.connector.version>
        <p6Spy.version>2.1.4</p6Spy.version>
        <flyway.version>4.0.3</flyway.version>
        <war.name>tpm</war.name>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
        <icefaces.version>3.3.0</icefaces.version>
        <el.version>2.2</el.version>
        <prettyfaces.version>3.3.3</prettyfaces.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.2</quartz.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
            <version>${p6Spy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>fruuts-business</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>${prettyfaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>${el.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${el.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${icefaces.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${icefaces.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
            <version>${icefaces.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.182</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependencies for using bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-servlet-2.x</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tried the suggested solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465872/com-mchange-v2-resourcepool-cannotacquireresourceexception-a-resourcepool-could) but in vain.
Any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: @Jens : I saw you've marked this thread as a duplicate. I just want to know please the reason behind this NullPointerException so I could be able to solve it.

Comment: Looks like the URL is null. Please check with a debugger